# What is the error in my query? I am trying to select data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, wordpress, join

I am using a MySQL database that includes many tables. I have 4 tables which are:

**site_location:**

```
siteID(PRIMARY KEY)
locationName
lat
long
```

**employee:**

```
employeeID(PRIMARY KEY)
employeeName
```

**inspection_info:**

```
inspectionID(PRIMARY KEY)
inspectionDate
employeeID
```

**inspection_site:**

```
inspectionID(PRIMARY KEY)

siteID(PRIMARY KEY)
```

where I have values in the **inspection_site** table

```
siteID 1 | inspectionID 1
siteID 1 | inspectionID 2
```

so my query must select  both values   but that is not happening it select the first or the second individually

SQL query:

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select 
           l.locationName
           , n.inspectionDate
           , e.employeeName
      from site_location l
      LEFT  
      JOIN inspection_site s
        on l.siteID = s.siteID
      LEFT
        JOIN inspection_info n
        on n.inspectionID = s.inspectionID
        LEFT
      JOIN employeeName e
        on n.employeeID=e.employeeID
         where 
        l.locationName = %s
        AND 
        e.employeeID = %d
        AND 
        n.inspectionID = %d
       ",$site_name,$soldier_name, $inspection_date);

     $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```

[image]

Comment: When you add a condition in an where section for a left joined table you actually made an INNER JOIN, so move the conditions from the left joined tables to the left join statement in the from section

Comment: And make sure that `l.locationName = %s` have actually registry for that parameter

Comment: @JorgeCampos about the first comment i did not understand your answer 
and for the second comment  l.locationName gets the right parameter

Comment: Just to be clear you talk about the `site_locaion` but your query is actually using `army_site_location` so I assumed that it is the same right?

Comment: yes its the same

Comment: Read this post carefully https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ and analise your tables data. See if you can figure it out. too busy to add an answer right now, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem

it was the **WHERE** in SQL query  where i specified to be matching the

- **locationName**
- **employeeID**
- **inspectionID**

in the **inspectionID** field it contain the relation for the **emplyee** table so it select the individual value that correspond to that ID.

so the solution was to just  ad the condition in **WHERE** for the **locationName**

## sql query :

```
$sql = $wpdb->prepare("select 
       l.locationName
       , n.inspectionDate
       , e.employeeName
  from army_site_location l

  JOIN inspection_site s
    on l.siteID = s.siteID

    JOIN inspection_info n
    on n.inspectionID = s.inspectionID

  JOIN employee e
    on n.employeeID=e.employeeID
    where 
    l.locationName = %s"
    ,$site_name);

 $query_submit =$wpdb->get_results($sql, OBJECT);
```